# SOQL Child -->Parent ---->Child

Tags: soql, relationships

I need to frame a SOQL in such a way that, from child i have to get the parent name and then i also need to get some data of another child of the same parent.

Example :

I have 3 objects

Invoice 
Subscription
Billing Account.

Invoice (Child) ------> Billing Account (Parent)
Subscription (Child) -------> Billing Account (Parent)

From Invoices , i needs to get the information of Subscription via  Billing Account .

**Please find the query i framed**

select Name,UM_Billing_Location__r.Name,UM_Billing_Location__r.csconta__Account__r.Name,**(select Name from UM_Billing_Location__r.csord__Subscription__r)** from UM_InvoiceHeader__c

I dont think so this part is correct
(select Name from UM_Billing_Location__r.csord__Subscription__r)

Kindly help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear about your question. This answer assumes you have two child objects of one parent object.

From [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) you need a `Left Outer Join` and a `Left Inner Join`, shown below:

```
id child1Id = ...;
Parent__c p = [
        select Name, (select ... from Child2s__r where ...)
        from Parent__c
        where Id in (select Parent__c from Child1__c where I = :child1Id)
        ];

String parentName = p.Name;
for (Child2__c child2 : p.Child2s__r) {
    ...
}
```

You can add `where`, `order by` and `limit` as needed to the `Child2__c` part of the query.